# не могу изменить тему wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu

у меня на VPS  на ней развернуто ubuntu server 22  я на нем развернул nginx на нем поставил wordpress - сайт открылся, обновил. Попробовал изменить тему, пишет что нет доступа. Сменил тему и такая же проблема. Проверил разрешения на папку с сайтом, стоит 775 и права передатся на вложенные файлы. Не могу понять как решить проблему, куда копать?

Comment: "Попробовал изменить тему, пишет что нет доступа. Сменил тему и такая же проблема."<-Это как понять? И кто пишет где пишет?

Comment: меняешь что либо в теме, вылетает сообщение: ''Сохранить не удалось"

Comment: Владелец файлов должен быть тот, под кем выполняется php. Файлы 644, папки 755.

Comment: тоже пробовал, не помогло.. Нашел как получить этот баг. Изменяешь формат постоянных ссылок и снова тему изменить нельзя...Возвращаешь в дефолт и все работает.